# MVC4 RegisterGoogleClient to request additional permissions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-contacts-api

I am very new to MVC, really liking it just getting used to everything.
One thing i would like to implement is the google log in (done) with ability to use the response as a way to get to the calender and the contacts API.

I am trying to find something that would speak to providing an API key with the RegisterGoogleClient method found in the AuthConfi.cs file.

I have registered an app with google and have the key that would request permissions for the calender and contacts. just cant seem to find the missing link for including this key with the RegisterGoogleClien.

Ideally i will be able to get the key passed in, user will see request for permissions to the additional items and then the OAuth key provided will be usable with the GData NuGet packages.

Thanks in advance!

ps- i am guessing i need to use the overload that allows for passing in a dictionary but can not find any documentation on that as well, probably just looking in the wrong place but i have been looking for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have the same problem as yours. I can authenticate the user (log in with google), but I cannot retrieve the user contacts. The access_token that is returned from gmail is not valid for accessing the user contacts. I need to authenticate the user, and in the same time to send my client_id and secret of the application that is registered at the google console. Then with that access_token probably I will be able to retrieve the user contacts.

```
RequestSettings r = new RequestSettings(app, access_token); // how to get the access_token ???
//if i have new RequestSettings(app, user_email, password); it works
ContactsRequest cRequest = new ContactsRequest(r);

Feed<Contact> feedContacts = cRequest.GetContacts(user.email);

List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (Contact gmailAddresses in feedContacts.Entries)
{
    // Looping to read email addresses
    foreach (EMail emailId in gmailAddresses.Emails)
    {
       list.Add(emailId.Address);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am sure that is the case, i am going to end up changing my approach a little and not used the built in if i can find the answer